# What's the use of runBlocking in kotlin if it blocks the current thread?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, nonblocking

I'm currently working on a codebase that is using `runBlocking` in a lot of places.
Here is an example

```
fun doSomeComputation() {
    val rows = runBlocking { //suspend function which queries database }
    //rows is used for further computation
}
```

From what I understand `runBlocking` blocks the current thread. So what is the benefit we are exactly getting by using it instead of using regular function? Read somewhere we use async code so that thread is not blocked and UI doesn't become unresponsive but how is using `runBlocking` async code since it is blocking the thread? 
I had the same doubt in javascript `async/await`
Since thread gets blocked why even use `await`?

Comment: it might be useful in the main function.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why we should not use `runBlocking()` as you do. `runBlocking()` is useful for starting our application, for example we can put a single `runBlocking()` in the `main()` to bootstrap coroutines and then we don't use it anywhere else. It is also useful to bridge suspendable and non-suspendable code if blocking is our expected result. But otherwise, we should avoid using it.

If we need to bridge classic and suspendable code, but we don't want to block the thread, then we need to stick to classic asynchronous techniques like futures or callbacks.

Comment: what about await in javascript?
I think it's recommended to be used.
But it also blocks the thread right. so why use it?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and never used its `async/await` feature, but I thought it doesn't block the thread. Does it?

Comment: I think it does.
`const response = await callSomeApi()
//code which is using that response executed only after the function is executed
`

Comment: Yes, it waits at this line, but it doesn't mean the thread is blocked. This is exactly the point of suspending in Kotlin and (as I believe) `async/await` feature in JavaScript.

Comment: got it. well now I wish kotlin haven't introduced `runBlocking`. our codebase is using it all over the places and I was comparing it to `await` for better clarity.

Comment: Equivalent of `async/await` in Kotlin is just invoking suspend function from another suspend function. It waits at the call site, but the thread is free to do something else. I guess `runBlocking()` does not really have any equivalent in JavaScript. As JavaScript is single-threaded, blocking never makes sense in it. Java/Kotlin is multi-threaded, so blocking is a normal practice (although not within coroutines), so `runBlocking()` actually makes sense in some cases.